# How to export diagrams as images in Papyrus 3.2.0?

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus

I have been working on a model for some weeks with Papyrus 3.2.0 on Eclipse 4.7.1a. This morning I wanted to start including some of the diagrams in a report but this version of Papyrus is unable to export diagrams as images using the *Export All Diagrams...* Menu ([Bug 529966](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=529966)).

Is there any way to circumvent this bug? What other options are there to obtain images (SVG, PDF, PNG, etc) from a diagram developed with Papyrus 3.2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [suggestions at the Eclipse Forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1091172&goto=1780149&#msg_1780149) I was able to identify that Papyrus 3.2.0 succeeds in exporting the diagram presently portrayed in the Designer view.

Therefore the way around this bug is to open each diagram in the Designer view and export them one by one (using the *Export All Diagrams...* menu).